# Can't select text with left click function

Tags: html, css

Noormally you can select text with left click function

[image: Example]

I work on this [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html) and am not able to select text in the top areas of the page.

What is wrong with the code?

HTML: [link](http://pastebin.com/MBDd6jFL)

CSS: [link](http://pastebin.com/V5SMXddZ)

Comment: In IE it does but in Chrome & Firefox not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footer is on top of the text. Just remove `position:absolute` form `#footer`

EDIT:

I can't replicate your issues because my solution is working. Here you can see it

[image: Here it is working]

Comment: I'm not that advanced, can you give me a solution? Actually I have messed up the whole Layout right now and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: All i needed to do was delete the code i mentioned, just one property. see here http://pastebin.com/xPhjp2pS

Comment: OK now it looks better. But when I inspect the footer in Chrome then it remains on top. How can I have it on the right position? Because its a bit strange to have the footer floating around on top.

Comment: I mean maybe its really not so good idea with the margins solution of each elements. But how could it be done the best way to not mess up everything?

Comment: Because when I give margin top for footer the content of footer is forced away from its actual position.

Comment: For completeness; the comments Kiirani made are correct. Positioning everything absolutely is asking for trouble. It would be a good idea to learn how to use the natural flow of the the page and only using positioning when you have to. Which is why I marked her answer as correct

Comment: @DanielHernandez for the specific problem of getting your footer to sit below the content -- this isn't really solvable given the current way your layout is laid out. `position:absolute` removes elements from standard page flow control, so your footer won't "automatically" flow beneath these elements anymore.  There's no one solution but I can recommend starting by removing position:absolute from almost everything :P

Answer (score 2):

I right clicked the offending text in firefox and used the "inspect element" option, which helpfully tells me what element is sitting directly below the mouse.

Your #footer div is sitting ontop of the text, due to having `position:absolute;` set with no actual positioning.

If you remove the `position:absolute;` from #footer and reposition it properly, your problem should go away.

*Related note: 

I notice that the way you're handling positioning content on the page is a bit weird - you're using `position:absolute` for nearly everything? 

It's outside of the scope of this answer but seriously consider moving away from this -- it's causing this problem and will probably give you a headache in future.  That thing you're doing where the contents of your footer have massive margins to push them further down the page past the content?  That's an unstable solution and a good sign that your layout has gone wrong somewhere.
This is a fairly simple layout and can be handled fine by basic flow control like floats...*

Comment: I'm not that advanced, can you give me a solution? Actually I have messed up the whole Layout right now and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct as I totally agree as the page is in essence not complicated to build using the normal page flow and a float here and there.

Comment: @DanielHernandez so there's no real nice way to say this -- become that advanced.   I'd love to rewrite your code for you, but I don't have time, nor do I have time to sit down and teach you how to deal with flow control in css. It's complicated and standard layouts are seeped in browser support history.  I recommend you find a tutorial which results in a layout similar to the one you want, and see if you can figure out how that code gives you a result.

Answer (score 1):

The footer div blocks the text so only the upper part is unselectable. You might want to change your layout or structure of your html and css to avoid blocking the text.

Take a look at this:
[image: Blockages]

Comment: I'm not that advanced, can you give me a solution? Actually I have messed up the whole Layout right now and don't know how to proceed.